# How do I sanitize input on a URL/IP address field on my site?

Tags: php, validation

I'm someone of a newbie. I'm not sure what the best way to prevent xss or injections on this field would be.

I have a field on my site that will take a user-submitted IP address or URL in order to complete a ping/traceroute test. I really only want to allow what HAS to be allowed for the thing to be functional. I have the whole thing working right now, but I'm not sure how to sanitize the input.

Basically, here's my function for ping. I don't know a LOT about output buffering, but it seemed like the easiest way to capture the output from the command.

```
function ping($domain){
   echo "</div>";
   $command = shell_exec("ping -c 3 $domain");
   ob_start();
   echo "<pre>$command</pre>";
   $output = ob_get_clean();
   echo "\n" . $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of PHP's built-in filtering with [filter_var()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
if($domain === filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) || $domain === filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)
{
    // run your existing code
}
else
{
    // invalid input
}
```

Comment: Up to date. I like it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure something like the following should work well:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$/i', $domain) &&
    !preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$/i', $domain))
    die('Not a valid domain!');
```

Example here: http://phpfiddle.io/fiddle/843401527